# Remove scientific notation on floats without forcing fixed width

Tags: c++

I am outputting a CSV of floats using an `ofstream`. 99% of the floats have an accuracy of 1-2 decimal places so simply using `fileOut.precision(3)` is enough to force the correct precision.

Every now and again a float will have an extremely low value and as such will be output with scientific notation aka `1e-007`. In this case I would ideally like `0`.

A lot of answers on here suggest using something similar to `fileOut.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);` to prevent this but this makes every field output as `0.000` regardless of whether or not it needs that many digits.

What I would like is for all floats to behave normally and not show scientific notation.

Is there anyway to do this or would I have to create a simple function that checks if a numebr is below, say, `0.001` and if so set it to 0?

**Update:**

I am now using the following code to wrap around any floats, it is not ideal but works.

```
float _RoundToZero(float in, int precision = 2)
{
  return in <= (1 / powf(10,precision)) ? 0.0 : in;
}
```

Comment: Why is it a problem to have the additional decimal places in the csv?

Comment: It makes it a lot bigger, the CSVs are stored on a flash card with limit space so would save a fair amount of space

Comment: How do you want these low numbers to be displayed?  As `0.000`?

Comment: I want any low numbers to ideally be represented by `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's impossible to achieve with `iostream` *and* `printf`. The only options are:

- implement your own floating point formatting routine to do the correct rounding.
- format the float into string and trim the zeros.
- if the value is less than a threshold then round it to zero.

The first is complicated, the last is inaccurate (can't represent exactly 10<sup>-n</sup> in binary floats).

All can be implemented by overriding the numput facet, which will allow you to leave the formatting code as clean as before.

Here is an implementation of the last option:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class my_put : public std::num_put<char> {
    iter_type do_put (iter_type out, ios_base& str, char_type fill, double val) const
    {
        streamsize prec = str.precision();
        if((str.flags() & ios_base::floatfield) == ios_base::fixed && fabs(val)*2 <= pow(10.0, -(int)prec))
            str.precision(0);
        out = std::num_put<char>::do_put(out, str, fill, val);
        str.precision(prec);
        return out;
    }
};

int main()
{
    double a[] = {123, 0, 0.001, 0.0001 };
    cout.imbue(locale(cout.getloc(), new my_put));
    cout.precision(3);
    cout.setf(ios_base::fixed, ios_base::floatfield);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        cout << a[i] << '\n';
}
```

See output here: http://ideone.com/qaV0w

Note that the correctness for the boundary case (0.0005) depends on the underlining floating point format and implementation.

Comment: @JohnDibling: your proposed hack falls into my last option, and as I said, it's inaccurate. When I say "it's impossible with *" I mean that there's no flag combination that will give you the results. Of course you can do it by other means that use printf/iostreams as one of the steps. But it does not contradict what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Consider printing the values multiplied by 100, as integers (rounding for accuracy). That way although you will get trailing zeroes sometimes, you will never have to print the decimal place, which will be wasting 1 character for each value.

Alternatively, write the float in binary. Since all floats will have the same size (4 bytes), you retain all the precision of the original without worrying about trailing zeroes, your file size is very predictable and you don't have to waste space delimiting the values. 100 values takes 400 bytes. In text format, a value takes a minimum of 2 bytes (number + field delimiter) and a maximum of whatever your format permits (including one for the decimal point) plus the delimiter. In that format, 4 bytes gets you 2 significant figures of precision, instead of the 5 or 6 of a float.